# How to map community structure with circular embedding and normalized edge weights?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request, charts

Given:

```
ClearAll[vl, el, ew, community, g];

vl = {"stel", "segw", "ma7", "str1", "str3", "str2", "swhl", "sest", 
   "min", "sfin", "scst", "ma12", "shot", "ma8", "soth", "srtl", 
   "ma15", "ma6", "str4", "sbus", "ma13"};
el = {"stel" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "stel" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sfin", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", 
   "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", "shot" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", 
   "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "min" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "min" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", 
   "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma13" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "str2" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "ma7" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", "soth" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7"};
ew = {0.01313, 0.0139, 0.0131, 0.0188, 0.01145, 0.01842, 
    0.01786, 0.01203, 0.0137, 0.0188, 0.018, 0.01561, 0.01544,  
    0.01767, 0.0174, 0.0133, 0.0184, 0.0126, 0.01724, 0.0126, 
    0.0139, 0.010414`, 0.0169, 0.01498, 0.01736, 0.01832, 
    0.01211, 0.011911, 0.01586`, 0.01863,0.01653, 0.01533, 
    0.0129, 0.0121, 0.01144, 0.014, 0.01109, 0.0172, 0.01267, 
    0.0171, 0.0150, 0.01192, 0.01428, 0.017406, 0.0109, 
    0.017892, 0.01338, 0.017794, 0.01095, 0.0187, 0.0155, 
    0.0142, 0.01422, 0.01125, 0.015559, 0.01788};
community = {{"stel", "segw", "str1", "str3", "str2", "sbus"}, {"ma7",
     "scst", "ma12", "shot", "soth", "str4"}, {"ma8", "srtl", "ma15", 
    "ma6", "ma13"}, {"swhl", "sest", "min", "sfin"}};
g = Graph[vl, el, EdgeWeight -> ew];

HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ community, 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Generates the following circular weighted graph:

[image]

I like to have a community graph with the following properties:

1. Community graph must take into account edge weights (i.e., use weighted community structure);
2. Community elements should be next to each other as a group and default arrows within communities be kept as they are;
3. Community area for each community should be of distinct color;
4. Between community edges should be normalized and communities be linked with a single arrow with thickness measured by the sum of normalized edge weights;
5. Since the incoming and outgoing arrows between communities may be of different thickness (as measured by normalized edge weights), the respective arrows should be shown separately.

The following chart is an example of what I like to create based on the 5 steps above. Within community links should also be shown as a default format.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from drawing graph based on community.
Compute vertex coordinates:

```
ccoord = 
  CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 
    21][[Ordering[VertexIndex[g, Flatten[community]]]]];
```

Draw a highlighted graph with only edges between the same community :

```
vfunc[{x_, y_}, _, rad_] := 
 With[{ang = ArcTan[x, y]}, 
  Line[{{Cos[ang - rad[[1]]], 
     Sin[ang - rad[[1]]] }, {Cos[ang + rad[[1]]], 
     Sin[ang + rad[[1]]] }}]]

hg = HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ community, 
  VertexCoordinates -> ccoord, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", "Circular"], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[
      BSplineCurve[{#[[1]], {0, 0}, #[[-1]]}, 
       SplineWeights -> {1, EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[-1]]]/10, 
         1}]] &), GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> vfunc]
```

[image]

create edges between communities with total weights:

```
m = Length[community];
member = Association[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[community -> Range[m]]]];
gedges = 
  GroupBy[EdgeList[g], {member[First[#]] &, member[Last[#]] &}, 
   Total[AnnotationValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]] &];
{cedges, cweights} = 
  Transpose[
   Flatten[Table[
     If[i != j && NumberQ[gedges[i, j]], {i -> j, gedges[i, j]}, 
      Nothing], {i, m}, {j, m}], 1]];
```

and draw lines with weight and colors:

```
astep = 2 Pi/VertexCount[g];
lc = Length /@ community;
cangles = 
  Table[angle, {n, lc}, {angle, 
     astep/2, (n - 1) astep - astep/2, (n - 2) astep/2 }] + 
   astep Most[FoldList[Plus, 0, lc]];
emap = Association@
   Table[i -> 
     AssociationThread[Delete[Range[m], i] -> Range[m - 1]], {i, m} ];

drawLine[Rule[i_, j_], cangles_, emap_, astep_, r_ : .9] :=
 Block[{a, b},
  a = cangles[[i, emap[i, j]]] + astep;
  b = cangles[[j, emap[j, i]]] - astep;
  a = r {Cos[a], Sin[a]};
  b = r {Cos[b], Sin[b]};
  Arrow[BSplineCurve[{a, {0, 0}, b}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, EuclideanDistance[a, b]/3, 1}]]
  ]

colors = 
  VertexStyle /. 
   AnnotationValue[{hg, {"stel", "ma7", "ma8", "swhl"}}, 
    GraphHighlightStyle];

edges = Riffle[
   Thread[Directive[Arrowheads /@ (3.5 cweights), 
     colors[[cedges[[All, 1]]]], Thickness /@ cweights]], 
   drawLine[#, cangles, emap, astep/3] & /@ cedges];
```

Put all together with PieChart:

```
clusterSector[gap_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, y_}, rest___] := 
  Block[{ngap = (xmax - xmin)/2}, 
   If[ngap < gap, ngap = ngap, ngap = gap];
   ChartElementData["Sector"][{{xmin + ngap, xmax - ngap}, y}, rest]];

irad = 9; gap = 0.01;
offset = Pi/VertexCount[g]; PieChart[{6, 6, 5, 4}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{-(offset*.9), "Counterclockwise"}, irad}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Show[{hg, Graphics[{Opacity[.8], edges}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
   2.2 { irad, irad}], ChartElementFunction -> clusterSector[5 gap], 
 ChartStyle -> (Directive[EdgeForm[#], #] & /@ colors), 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

more label scheme:

```
nmaps = AssociationThread[Rule @@ Transpose[StringSplit[names, ": "]]];
Show[{PieChart[{6, 6, 5, 4}, 
   SectorOrigin -> {{-(offset*.9), "Counterclockwise"}, irad}, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Show[{ Graph[hg, VertexLabels -> _ -> None], 
       Graphics[{Opacity[.8], edges}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
     2 { irad, irad}], ChartElementFunction -> clusterSector[5 gap], 
   ChartStyle -> (Directive[EdgeForm[#], #] & /@ colors), 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], 
  PieChart[
   Thread[Callout[ConstantArray[1, Length[Flatten[community]]], 
     Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ Flatten[community] /. nmaps]], 
   ChartElementFunction -> ({} &), 
   SectorOrigin -> {{-(1.8 offset), "Counterclockwise"}, irad}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{300, 200}, {50, 20}}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

```
Show[{PieChart[{6, 6, 5, 4}, 
   SectorOrigin -> {{-(offset*.9), "Counterclockwise"}, irad}, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Show[{ Graph[hg, VertexLabels -> _ -> None], 
       Graphics[{Opacity[.8], edges}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
     2 { irad, irad}], ChartElementFunction -> clusterSector[5 gap], 
   ChartStyle -> (Directive[EdgeForm[#], #] & /@ colors), 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], 
  PieChart[ConstantArray[1, Length[Flatten[community]]], 
   ChartElementFunction -> ({} &), 
   ChartLabels -> 
    Placed[Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ Flatten[community] /. nmaps, 
     "VerticalCallout"], ImagePadding -> {{200, 100}, {0, 0}}, 
   SectorOrigin -> {{-(1.8 offset), "Counterclockwise"}, irad}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{300, 300}, {10, 10}}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: All is perfect!!! Maybe because of my MMA version 13.1, when I run the code I get the following message `drawLine is not a Graphics primitive or directive` and hence `PieChart` does not show the thick colored arrows. Do you have any idea about where the problem is? Again, this is a very nice code. Thanks again.

Comment: The thick arrows between communities are normalized edge weights, right?

Comment: @TugrulTemel There was typo.  It should work now.  Thickness are based on the total edge weights between communities.

Comment: Now it works nicely. Thanks again...

Comment: Sorry for coming back for additional question related to the presentation of the final figure with thick arrows above. I also like to use full names of the vertex names within individual communities. For example, `swhl` has a name `wholesale sector`. How can I adjust that figure to introduce `Callout` with full sector names for all vertex names?

Comment: @TugrulTemel maybe.. try to change Epilog to Inset[Show[{PieChart[
    Thread[Callout[ConstantArray[1, Length[Flatten[community]]], 
      Flatten[community]]], ChartElementFunction -> ({} &), 
    SectorOrigin -> {{-(1.8 offset), "Counterclockwise"}, .1}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], Graph[hg, VertexLabels -> _ -> None],
    Graphics[{Opacity[.8], edges}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
 3.1 { irad, irad}] and add ImagePadding -> 30 or more?

Comment: which parameters are you using to adjust the thickness of the arrows in the figure? I tried many things but I cannot really adjust the length and the thickness of the arrows between communities.

Comment: @TugrulTemel You can rescale cweights to adjust thickness (used inside edges). For length, easiest way could be use set back of Arrow in drawLine function like Arrow[..., {s1, s2}]

Comment: Thank you very much...

Comment: I was trying to use your code to get the very last figure above, but all of a sudden I started to get the following error and the between community edges are not shown properly. Here is the error `Part::partw: Part 2 of {-(\[Pi]/16)+\[Pi]^2/32} does not exist.

Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.112076} does not exist.

Part::partw: Part 2 of {0.112076} does not exist.

General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation.` Could you please let me know where I can adjust in the code to correct this error.